# Make an Image(s) appear after hovering over an <a> tag(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working with buttons and images. I have seen several tutorials for gettting a button to appear after hovering over an image. I am trying to do the reverse of this operation. My question: how can I get a picture(s) to appear after hovering over an a `<a>` tag(s) with jquery? Is it possible?

**HTML**

```
    <a href="example.htm" class="large magenta awesome">Cheeseburger »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large blue awesome">Tacos »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large red awesome">Salads »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large orange awesome">Bread Sticks »</a>
    <a href="example.htm" class="large yellow awesome">Dessert »</a>
```

Comment: If there is an example, yes, it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Two upvotes in under a minute for this question? Seriously?

Comment: And where in the document is the image, in relation to the `a` elements? Does it exist already, or is it dynamically created?

Comment: +1 for naming your CSS class "awesome". Just kidding, this was a horribly phrased question and kudos to Bram for figuring out what he actually wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best idea is to use a `data-[type]` and compare it with an ID, class or other data-type. You can also do this with a class ofcourse.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/7Wp9z/54/). And here is the jQuery code:

```
$("div#links > a").hover(
    function() {
        var ID = $(this).data("content");
        $("div#images").children("img#" + ID).fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function() {
        var ID = $(this).data("content");
        $("div#images").children("img#" + ID).stop(true).hide();
    }
);​
```

Comment: Great solution! I would just suggest changing the first callback to     $("div#images").children("img#" + ID).fadeIn("slow").siblings().hide(); So that, there is no chance to see more then one image at the same time in case of fast mouse movement hover the links.

Comment: @cacoroto I agree that fast mouse movement might result in multiple images on screen, but I don't think your solution works (tried it) because the `fade` effect is still happening. To counter this, we could use `stop`. I updated my post and edited the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery's hover method, which works like this:

```
$('a.orange').hover(
    function() {
        $('.someImage').show();
    },
    function() {
        $('.someImage').hide();
    }
);
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $('a').hover(
>    function(){
>       $('img').show();
>    }, 
>    function(){
>       $('img').hide();
>    } 
> );
> ```

Comment: Doesn't he want to hide the image on mouseenter, then show it on mouseleave? Just switch your `hide()` and `show()` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only css, if you need change img into your A tag

```
.img{
    background: #222 url(/images/alert-overlay.png);
}
.img_hover{
    background: #222 url(/images/alert-overlay-hover.png);
}
```

with jquery

```
$('a.orange').hover(
    function() {

        $(this).removeClass('img').addClass('img_hover');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass('img_hover').addClass('img');
    }
);
```

or only with jquery

```
 $('a.orange').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrlHover + ')');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).css('background-image','url(' + imageUrl + ')');
        }
    );
```

Comment: _Every_ solution here uses CSS. Even `.show()` and `.hide()` simply toggle `display:none`